# How to read Cookies from iOS Safari app using SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, safari, sfsafariviewcontroller

I need to read cookies from Safari app to inside the my application. So is there any way to do it by using any SFSafariViewController inside the our application. Please help me on it.

Thanks in advance.

**Edited**

I have a one URL https://example.com/abc123 and when I open this URL in Safari application it sets some cookies automatically. Now I have to open my application and read those cookies by passing the domain (https://example.com).

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *sharedHTTPCookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
NSArray *cookies = [sharedHTTPCookieStorage cookiesForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://wwwexample.com"]];
```

Is it possible to read cookies?

Comment: were you able to get a solution for this?

Comment: We found another way to read cookie through API as we can get Safari cookies directly into apps. @Nameet

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, there's no way you can read cookies using `SFSafariViewController`. You need to use `WKWebView` or `UIWebView` for that. For using `UIWebView` to retrieve cookies, you can use it delegate method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

      NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookiesStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
      NSURLRequest *urlReq = webView.request;
      NSURL *url = urlReq.URL;
      NSArray *cookies = [cookiesStorage [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL:url]];
}
```

Comment: Is it possible read Cookies from Safari app if I use WKWebView in side my app?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can also use `UIWebView` to get cookies. I have edited my answer to include some code just for reference

Comment: @GaneshGuturi, Have you tried accessing `NSHTTPCookie` object inside the `cookies` array? Please let me know

Comment: Yes I tried. I was getting nil. The array count also '0'.